# Running mkdir -p remotely via ssh results in is not a valid local path or glob error

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, devops, fabric

I'm using Fabric (http://www.fabfile.org) framework which connects via ssh to a VPS (Droplet on DigitalOcean) to push some bash commands.

Running a simple bash command mkdir fails with

```
ValueError: 'mkdir -p /opt/create_this_dir' is not a valid local path or glob.
```

What could be the problem here? When I log into the VPS via ssh as root, I'm able to run

```
"mkdir -p /opt/create_this_dir"
```

and the directory gets created under /opt/ without same error I get when I run command remotely with fabric script seen in screenshot below.

[image: Here is a pic of the problem]

Comment: Don't post illegible pictures — show us the text in the question!

Answer (score 0):

I need to use

```
run("sudo mkdir -p /opt/reimaginedworks")
```

instead of

```
put("sudo mkdir -p /opt/reimaginedworks")
```